# How to make generic the formula parameter of naiveBayes() in R?

Tags: r, classification, naivebayes

When I'm using the function `naiveBayes()` of the library `"e1071"` it is required to insert a formula of the type:

```
myFormula <- myClass~ feature1 + feature2 + feature3
```

If I want to make it generic (I don't know how many features has the relative dataset) how can I do? I just know the `myClass` column will be the last one, and I want to keep in considerations all other columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to all other columns dynamically with the `.`.

```
myFormula <- cyl ~ .
naiveBayes(myFormula, data = mtcars)



    Call:
naiveBayes.default(x = X, y = Y, laplace = laplace)

A-priori probabilities:
Y
      4       6       8 
0.34375 0.21875 0.43750 

Conditional probabilities:
   mpg
Y       [,1]     [,2]
  4 26.66364 4.509828
  6 19.74286 1.453567
  8 15.10000 2.560048

   disp
Y       [,1]     [,2]
  4 105.1364 26.87159
  6 183.3143 41.56246
  8 353.1000 67.77132
```

If you want the class dymanic, you can use `substitute` the formula and use `eval` to evaluate it inside the `naiveBayes` function call.

```
dynamicNB <- function(data, class) {
  myFormula <- substitute(class ~ .)
  naiveBayes(eval(myFormula), data = data)
}

dynamicNB(class = mpg, data = mtcars)
```

Comment: Running this:  `naiveBayes(myFormula, data = df)` I obtain `Error in model.frame.default(formula = myFormula, data = df, na.action = function (object,  : variable lengths differ (found for 'Class')`. Maybe using the dot includes also the last column (with the "class attribute"?) I don't understand

Comment: Also I know it may look confusing but `Class` is the first attribute, while `Survived` the "class attribute" (I'm also using the Titanic dataset)

Comment: tried it with the mtcars dataset, also with with the second column. Can you use `dput ` to provide your data?

Comment: I also tried with your code and I get the same results.
The problem with mine is maybe that I also want to generically call the Class name so I'm trying with this: `myFormula <- colnames(df)[ncol(df)]~ .` (as `colnames(df)[ncol(df)]` produces the string "Survived" in case of the Titanic dataset)

Comment: I understand, I guess I get what you want :)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, but it's still not working :(
`Error in model.frame.default(formula = eval(myFormula), data = data, na.action = function (object,  : variable lengths differ (found for 'x') `

Where `x` is the name of the first column (I changed dataset)
Any idea why am I getting that?

Comment: try to post some sample data with the `dput` function

Comment: The main point about my question was to obtain that `~.`. For the moment I can use just a couple of if-else statements for the class one, so I marked your answer as the correct one: thanks again!